# Creating a new object every time you call a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

I have a recommender system that I need to train, and I included the entire training procedure inside a function:

```
def train_model(data):
  model = Recommender() 
  Recommender.train(data)
  pred = Recommender.predict(data)
  return pred
```

something like this. Now if I want to train this inside a loop, for different datasets, like:

```
preds_list = []
data_list = [dataset1, dataset2, dataset3...]
for data_subset in data_list:
  preds = train_model(data_subset)
  preds_list += [preds]
```

How can I make sure that every time I call the `train_model` function, a brand new instance of a recommender is created, not an old one, trained on the previous dataset?

Comment: ... you instantiate a new instance and return it. It seems like that is what your function does already, no? What is the actual issue you are encountering?

Comment: my recommender has very similar accuracy on vastly different (both user type and number of users) datasets. I suspect it's using the same recommender over and over, with every call.

Comment: Can you please give more context about the `Recommender`? The function `train_model` should give a new instance each time, given `Recommender()` is a function. But if instances of `Recommender` share state, you may be running into issues with that

Comment: If you want to check the identity of an object, you can always do `print(id(model))`, which will print the memory location identity of `model`

Comment: The recommender is basically from here: http://surpriselib.com/ , the algo = SVD() object.

Comment: Well, you'd have to know something about the `Recommender` class, perhaps it always returns the same instance (singleton pattern, something not generally seen in Python but nothing is stopping people from writing it that way). In any case, it seems this is your *suspicion* based on not exactly hard evidence. I suspect you are indeed creating multiple instances of Recommender, if your code is as shown

Comment: I see, I will further investigate the class from the library I use, and see if there are any issues there.

Comment: @EdwardMinnix `id` is only guaranteed for the lifetime of the object. In this case, the object is being created and destroyed in a loop, and each new object may very well may re-use the same `id` . Note, `id(x)` simply prints an *id that guaranteed to be unique for the lifetime of an object*. In CPython, this *happens* to be the memory location of the PyObject header. That may not be the case in other implementations.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga True, but that can help find if something is a singleton

Comment: You aren't actually doing `Recommender.train(data)`, are you?

Comment: Why don't you just link us to the actual documentation for `Recommender`? Or are you actually not providing us with a [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already creating a new instance everytime you execute `train_model`. The thing you are not using the new instance.
You probably meant:

```
def train_model(data):
  model = Recommender() 
  model.train(data)
  pred = model.predict(data)
  return pred
```

Comment: Also, you can always double-check by checking the id of the returned objects using ```id()```.

Comment: @myke that depends on exactly how you do it. You can very easily get misleading results if you are creating and destroying the same type of object on each iteration (as the OP is doing...)

Comment: @myke: Not really, because ID values are only guaranteed to be distinct for objects with overlapping lifetimes.

Comment: Good points, @juanpa.arrivillaga et al. This would mean that I can't be sure two objects are the same just because their ids are the same. But the other way round (which seems more relevant in this use case) would work: If you get different ids, you can be sure the objects are different. Correct?

Comment: Your answer is correct because the OP does indeed create a new object, `model`, in every function call, BUT this new model` is never used after it has been instantiated and what the function returns is not the new `model,`  it's the value of `Recommender.predict(data)` that, as far as we know (it is a very poor question) could be everything.

Answer (score 0):

Use the instance you've instantiated, not the class

```
    class Recommender:
        def __init__(self):
            self.id = self

        def train(self, data):
            return data

        def predict(self, data):
            return data + str(self.id)


    def train_model(data):
      model = Recommender() 
      model.train(data)
      return model.predict(data)

    data = 'a data '
    x = {}
    for i in range(3):
        x[i] = train_model(data)
        print(x[i])

    # a data <__main__.Recommender object at 0x11cefcd10>
    # a data <__main__.Recommender object at 0x11e0471d0>
    # a data <__main__.Recommender object at 0x11a064d50>
```